# React-Hook-Form is not registering dynamic props

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I am using react-hook-form and MUI to handle a form. The code is given below

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

const CreateMenu = ({ parent }) => {
  /* ++++ Implementing React-Hook-Form starts ++++ */
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data);
  /* ---- Implementing React-Hook-Form ends ---- */

  return (
    <Box>
      <Box
        sx={{ backgroundColor: "#f0f0f0", borderRadius: "10px 10px 0 0", p: 2 }}
      >
        <Typography
          variant="h5"
          sx={{
            color: "#444444",
            textTransform: "uppercase",
            letterSpacing: "2px",
          }}
        >
          CREATE MENU
        </Typography>
      </Box>
      {/*++++ Inputs start ++++*/}
      <form action="" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <Box sx={{ p: 2, backgroundColor: "#fafafa" }}>
          {/*++++ Parent starts ++++*/}
          <Grid container sx={{ my: 1 }}>
            <Grid
              item
              xs={4}
              sx={{
                display: "flex",
                alignItems: "center",
              }}
            >
              <Typography variant="body1" sx={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>
                Parent
              </Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={8}>
              <TextField
                id="outlined-basic"
                disabled
                value={parent?.name ? parent.name : ""}
                variant="outlined"
                sx={{ width: "100%" }}
                placeholder="Please Select Parent"
                {...register("parent")}
               
              />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          {/*---- parent ends ----*/}
          {/* ++++ Title Starts ++++ */}
          <Grid container sx={{ my: 1 }}>
            <Grid
              item
              xs={4}
              sx={{
                display: "flex",
                alignItems: "center",
              }}
            >
              <Typography variant="body1" sx={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>
                Title
              </Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={8}>
              <TextField
                id="outlined-basic"
                label="Title"
                variant="outlined"
                sx={{ width: "100%" }}
                {...register("title")}
              />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          {/* ---- Title ends ---- */}
          {/* Save Button Starts */}
          <Box sx={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "flex-end" }}>
            <Button type="submit" variant="contained">
              Save
            </Button>
          </Box>
          {/* Save Button Ends */}
        </Box>
      </form>
      {/*---- Inputs end ----*/}
    </Box>
  );
};

export default CreateMenu;
```

The  `{...register("title")}` is working fine. Here `parent` is a dyanmic prop. `{...register("parent")}` is not updating the `data` in onSubmit. It returns:

> {parent: undefined, title: 'menu', end_point: '', router_link: '', position: ''}

Even though the `<TextField>` is updated according to the `{parent.name}`

How to update the parent in returned data in `onSubmit`

- I tried providing `defaultValue` and still failed.